# Why is Negasonic Teenage Warhead so different in the Deadpool film?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, adaptation-comparison, deadpool, deadpool-2016

Negasonic Teenage Warhead appears in the films to have the powers of Cannonball from the X-Men comics.

Why was the character changed so much? Normally Negasonic Teenage Warhead has telepathic/pre-cognitive powers.

Comment: Have you listened to the commentary of the deleted scenes on the Blu-Ray?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Cannonball was originally intended for the movie because,  to quote Tim Miller

> "In the original script the action in the third act was great, but it was just Deadpool and a lot of guns

But they were worried about him being perceived as a hick:

> "We thought about Cannonball, but he would’ve been a stupid hick character, whereas the guys wrote Negasonic as this deadpan goth teen, which was a great angle.

They choose the character based in the name,  and spliced in the powers:

> I went through the list of Marvel characters ... And at the end of that list was Negasonic, which I just thought was a freaky, funny name.

[Source](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/deadpool-trailer-breakdown/)

Comment: Forgot my source!

Comment: Wow! So Cannonball was excluded because of bigotry! Very interesting find. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Nonsense. He was excluded because Marvel knows their audience and didn't want him to appear as a stereotypical redneck. Given the base audience the movie appealed to, I think it was a wise choice to make the character a goth. Who would play as understated in comparison to Deadpool's complete lack of restraint. This was savvy marketing and creative licensing.

Comment: Since you've highlighted that they spliced the powers, rather than replaced them, considered referencing the commentary from the deleted scenes. Available on the Blu-Ray.

Comment: @DrunkCynic not that I have the Blu-ray...

Comment: @AncientSwordRage https://youtu.be/roWyEYQDgY4?t=5m25s

Comment: Not related to the OP, but from your answer's quote about the third act, I heard the main reason it was changed was not the reason cited.  What I've been told (no official source, my friend was quoting an interview by I don't know which), was that their tight budget was already stressed, and gunfights are expensive. Since they liked the classic "gear up trope" they left that in and added the gag about the guns to explain it in verse.

Answer (score 6):

**"We changed her powers because we thought it was funnier"**

In a Q & A podcast the screenwriters Paul Wernick and Rhett Reese admitted that they only wanted to include the character because of her name and that they changed her powers because it was funnier.

[Q & A Podcast with Paul Wernick and Rhett Reese](https://secure-hwcdn.libsyn.com/p/4/f/a/4fae83aa2780ab82/DeadpoolQandA.mp3?c_id=10977945&expiration=1466439716&hwt=2bd56c47011c9b07d9b22230a76e239d)

At around 29:30 they answer the question as to the reason for the character being in the movie,

> Negasonic was there because Tim [Miller] wanted some good guy super powers in the movie

And at 29:42 they answer the question as to why they wanted her,

> Q: Why her? Why did you choose Negasonic?
>
> A: Because of the name.

Then they talk about how they changed her powers, and how she was a mind reader or was able to look into the future, 29:50

> In fact we changed her powers, we made her into a literal warhead because we thought that was funnier.

There is a lot of other great stuff in the podcast if you have time to listen to it.

And this on how they had to get permission from the studio,

> **It was the one thing we needed Marvel’s actual approval on**, that they
> had to reach out for. Tim [Miller] has a relationship with [Marvel
> President] Kevin Feige and I think he went straight to Kevin because
> all the lawyers, you know, it gets messy with the lawyers.

Comment: There was another interview (perhaps the Nerdist podcast?) I heard where he said again that he liked the name (its from a Monster Magnet song name, btw), but the character's powers from the comics didn't really match the name, so they were changed for powers that did. We're probably lucky Marvel didn't add "Awwww Space Lord Motha Motha" too.

Comment: @T.E.D., I am guessing there are a few interviews where some of the answers differ or needed to be elaborated on. I am guessing there were a few reasons then.