# Why was Angel Dust a villain in the Deadpool film?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

Based on <strike>my deep research</strike> reading [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_Dust_(comics)), [Angel Dust](http://marvel.com/universe/Angel_Dust) seems to be someone who's either neutral or a hero. Moreover, as a Morloc she isn't really affiliated/engaged with either the X-Men or Francis or anyone like that.

Is there any information from the film’s creators on why she ended up as a **villain**, serving Francis?

Related: " [Why is Negasonic Teenage Warhead so different in the Deadpool film?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121631/why-is-negasonic-teenage-warhead-so-different-in-the-deadpool-film) " and " 
[How was Angel Dust able to successfully fight Colossus?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133630/how-was-angel-dust-able-to-successfully-fight-colossus) "

Answer (score 8):

I do not have a good source at the moment for this, but my understanding is that they originally intended to have [Arclight](http://www.wow.com/wiki/Arclight_(comics)) of the Marauders as the villain but, much as with employing Cannonball, the licensing got problematic, so they moved to a more obscure character, keeping the powerset but changing the name.

Here is an image of Arclight from her spot in the Deadpool video game. Notice the similarities in powers and costume to the movie's Angel Dust.

[image: Ad for Deadpool video game featuring Arclight] [image: Deadpool film, Angel Dust]